# jQuery: Custom event doesn't run

Tags: jquery, html, playframework, jquery-2.0

I've currently come to a jQuery problem which cost me multiple hours so far and I still can't figure out what's going wrong exactly.
Long story short - my code is part of a memory game written in Play Framework.

jQuery file (simplified):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".card-grid").on("myEvent", '.card', function (event) {
        $(".card-grid").flip({
            trigger: 'click'
        });
    });
    $("#triggerButton").click(function () {
        $(".card-grid").trigger("myEvent");
    });
});
```

Explanation: The memory "cards" are loaded onto the page after initial loading using other (working) jQuery code. One .card div is loaded each into one .card-grid div. I need to run the flip method for the jQuery-flip plugin to work. jQuery version is 2.1.4 (flip won't run on more recent versions).

If I replace `myEvent` in the first method with, for example, `click`, I can just click one of the cards and the function runs just fine.

If I create another function, lets say

```
$(".test").on("myEvent", function (events) {
    $(this).text("Testtext").show();
});
```

and change the target of my button, the text shows just fine inside a .test object.

I'd really appreciate if anybody could tell me what's wrong.

Comment: might be an issue with propagation? have you tried: `$(".card-grid .card").trigger("myEvent");` in your second method?

Comment: Thanks, worked! But now you owe me an explanation. I thought I just need to "send" the event to the one listener I declared in my first method?!

Comment: reformatted below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct, however, `$(".card-grid").on("myEvent", '.card', funct...` targets all divs called `.card` that are child elements of `.card-grid`.

Hence, `$(".card-grid .card").trigger("myEvent");` makes for a better target for your `$("#triggerButton").click...` function.